# Delimit concatenated columns

Tags: c#, concatenation, string.format

I have the following issue.

I receive from a sql stored procedure some columns. 
After exporting them in `xls` format in the interface, we log some of the info into a sql table after concatenating it.
In `c#` we concatenate a certain number of columns using the `string.format` method:
ex:

```
string.Format("{0}+{1}", "column1", "column2");

output: column1column2
```

I want to be able to insert a pipe or any other character between the columns.
The output shoul be something like this:

```
column1|column2
```

Comment: `string.Format("{0}+{1}", "column1", "column2");` cannot give you `column1column2`.

Comment: Save us from guessing. Are `column1` and `column2` variables or string constants?

Comment: the columns are variable that come from the sql query in the stored procedure. We concatenate those columns in one and send it to a table in sql. The format that is received in this column is column1column2.

please not that i am an absolute newbie to c# at the moment ..

Answer (score 5):

This is what `String.Join` was intended for.

[String.Join documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string[] columns = {"column1", "column2"};
string output = String.Join("|", columns);
//output now contains : "column1|column2"
```

Comment: The problem with string.join is that it only brings the table's column names. Not the information in them.
That and the fact that i can't implicitly convert string to system.datacolumn

Comment: @Sorin you never mentioned the use of `system.datacolumn`.
If you intend to add the actual values of datacolumns to your output, you might want look up how to iterate over data rows. (assuming you are using `system.dataset` or `system.datatable`), but i think that is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

imo `string.Format("{0}+{1}", "column1", "column2");` should output `column1+column2` instead of `column1column2`

to insert a pipe between your values you just need to replace your `+`

```
string.Format("{0}|{1}", "column1", "column2");
```

Comment: This and every other variation gives sintax or operand error.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `column1` and 'columns2` are variables, What you then need is:

```
string.Format("{0}|{1}", column1, column2);
```

which for values of `23` and `25`, for example, would give you an output of `23|25`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var column1 = "column1";
 var column2 = "column2";
 var delimiter = "|";

 var result = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", column1, delimiter, column2);

 Console.WriteLine(result);
```

//Output

```
column1|column2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# 6.0 you can also use string interpolation

```
var result = $"{column1}|{column2}";
```